# Java Generics in Method Declaration

Tags: java, generics

```
   private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        //code to put the T Object in the Map
    }
```

I saw this code in a talk from Joshua Bloch on UserGroupsAtGoogle  
link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg

I wonder what this `<T>` means in the method declaration of the `putFavorite` method.

 I assume, this is not the return value, because this is already `void`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, it's not the return value, the `<T>` is declaring a generic type named `T` which will then be used in the signature of this method. For a client calling the method, they have to make sure the arguments they pass in satisfy the signature, such that `T` is consistent across all arguments (and return value in some cases).

Some valid ways to call the method would be:

```
putFavorite(String.class, "Some string");
putFavorite(Integer.class, Integer.valueOf(1234));
putFavorite(SomeClass.class, new SomeClass());
```

etc..

See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

is a type parameter which is replaced by the argument like in the example above. Here is a related faq : http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ001